# Any ideas why "GoToAsync" doesn't work in AppShell.cs?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Register detail page routes

**AppShell.cs**

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
    {
        public AppShell(string message)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ItemDetailPage), typeof(ItemDetailPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NewItemPage), typeof(NewItemPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute("LoginPage", typeof(LoginPage));
if (message != "main") {
                
                
                int itemid = Int32.Parse(message);
                var item = App.Database.GetItemAsyncId(itemid).Result;
                var itemValue = new Models.Item
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Description = item.Description,
                    Text = item.Text
                };
                OnItemSelected(itemValue);
                   }
    }
         public async void OnItemSelected(Item item)
        {  
         await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("LoginPage");
       //Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?{nameof(ItemDetailViewModel.ItemId)}={item.Id}");
      
        }}
```

When I launch the application on the emulator, the application should launch the pages:

1. "AboutPage" - starts;
2. "LoginPage" - it does not start.
   "LoginPage" should load using
   `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("LoginPage");`

The editor does not show errors.

is navigationStack

```
    <FlyoutItem x:Name="ItemsPage" Icon="icon_feed.png">
        <ShellContent Route="ItemsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem x:Name="About" Icon="icon_about.png">
        <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    

    <!-- When the Flyout is visible this will be a menu item you can tie a click behavior to  -->
    <MenuItem Text="Logout" StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle" Clicked="OnMenuItemClicked">
    </MenuItem>

    <!--
        TabBar lets you define content that won't show up in a flyout menu. When this content is active
        the flyout menu won't be available. This is useful for creating areas of the application where 
        you don't want users to be able to navigate away from. If you would like to navigate to this 
        content you can do so by calling 
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
    -->
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
    </TabBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your method get called?
What is the value of the message variable? Check if the `if (message != "main")` is true sometimes
It will only happen on the constructor.

[Edit]

To navigate a page of a Shell inside the constructor, you will have to replace `"Shell.Current.GoToAsync('LoginPage')"` with `"this.GoToAsync('LoginPage')"`

At the moment of the instance, the created Shell is not the "Current" shell of the application

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: yes, the method is being called. I checked it with the help of ```DisplayAlert("Alert", $"{item.Text}", "OK");```

Comment: With your code I get an error because you have an await inside a function that is not async.

Comment: But I still do not understand your code. What is your navigationStack? Where do you create your AppShell? Because if you are calling it from another Shell, then you might have to replace the "Shell.Current.GoToAsync" with an "this.GoToAsync"

Comment: @JuanSturla Where do you create your AppShell?  – I created a standard tabbed app. I added async. I added navigationStack. i edited my question.

Comment: With navigation stack I meant : what is your main page and when do you instantiate your Shell with the message variable. Try editing the OnItemSelected. Replace "Shell.Current" with "this". `public async void OnItemSelected(Item item)
        {  
         await this.GoToAsync("LoginPage");
          }`

Comment: 1. I incorrectly configured the comparison in app. cs during the upgrade because of this, the "message" variable always had the value "main" because of this, the "onItemSelected" method was never launched.

Comment: 2) ***replacing "shell.current" with "this" helped. *** Or you can leave only "GoToAsync". But unfortunately, it was not possible to launch the "LoginPage" page. It's good that the real goal was to launch the page along the path ```GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?{nameof(ItemDetailViewModel.ItemId)}={item.Id}");```

Comment: If the Shell is your rootpage it should not have much logic inside of it. You might want to move it to another page, like the ItemsPage. The replacing of "Shell.current" worked because when you create the Shell object, at that moment that is not the Shell.Current of the application, that happens later. I am glad it helped! If that is all, I will update the answer, so you can mark it as the solution and we can help the people than come to this post